# Angular Eonasdan Datetimepicker in Formly-Form not Validating

Tags: angularjs, validation, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Having problem getting  Eonasdan `datetimepicker` field to validate.
I am using ngMessages, and my **Name** field is validating just fine.

Here is template I am using for `datetimepicker`:

```
<script type='text/ng-template' id='datetimepicker.html'>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': vm.event.date.$invalid }">
          <label for="{{::id}}">{{options.templateOptions.label}}</label>
          <div class='input-group'>
            <input type="text"
                id="{{::id}}" 
                name="{{::id}}" 
                class="form-control" 
                required
                datetimepicker
                ng-model="vm.event"
                options="vm.options"
                 />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

...and here is the template for `error-messages`

```
<script type='text/ng-template' id='error-messages.html' >
    <formly-transclude></formly-transclude>
    <div ng-messages="fc.$error" ng-if="event.$submitted || options.formControl.$touched" class="error-messages">
      <div ng-message="{{ ::name }}" ng-repeat="(name, message) in ::options.validation.messages" class="message">
        {{ message(fc.$viewValue, fc.$modelValue, this)}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-messages="fc[0].$error" ng-if="event.$submitted || options.formControl[0].$touched" class="error-messages">
      <div ng-message="{{ ::name }}" ng-repeat="(name, message) in ::options.validation.messages" class="message">
        {{ message(fc[0].$viewValue, fc[0].$modelValue, this)}}
       </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

An example using the versions I am working with... [Eonasdan DateTimePicker Validation](http://plnkr.co/edit/zTyU8ilEFfl6N2Qfucmd?p=preview)

In the example, you can see that the outline of input boxes turn red, but no validation message is displayed.